# Ruby will not recognize Diet module, will recognize Diets module

Tags: ruby, module, typeerror

I have a main file, simple_carbon_calculator.rb, that requires a number of different files, but namely diet.rb. Both files require a data file, constants_and_converesions.rb.

In simple_carbon_calculator.rb:

```
require_relative 'constanst_and_conversions.rb'
require_relative 'diet.rb'
# Other Code
Diet.get_diet_emissions
```

In diet.rb:

```
require_relative 'constants_and_conversions.rb'
module Diet
  def self.get_diet_emissions
    ## function
  end
end
```

When I run simple_carbon_calculator.rb, the TypeError is raised: "Diet is not a module" However, when I change the module to be named Diets (note the s), it works fine. I honestly have no idea why. Any thoughts?

Cheers and thanks,
Reid

Comment: It shouldn't matter, both Diet and Diets work for me. You've probably had a typo somewhere

Comment: Have you defined Diet as a class anywhere?

Comment: what's in `constanst_and_conversions.rb`? seems like the hidden code is the where the issue might be resolved...